# TYPO3 7.6.15 htmlarea buttons has no icons

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I got a weired problem with my RTE after updating to 7.6.15. it looks like this

htmlarea buttons without icons

[image]

It seems, that the spritesheet "actions.png" (typo3/sysext/t3skin/rtehtmlarea/images/sprites) is not loaded.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the usual information?

- does the file exist?
- is the file accessible?
- what does the browser (e.g. firebug) report? (console, net)

Comment: yes, the file exists, yes it is accessible, but the console does not show any errors. it only displays the default messages with end with "Editor ready"

Comment: also no abnormality in the tab 'net'? is there a try to load the file? with correct response? have you tried to load the sprites file by hand in your browser? (maybe with a forced reload to refill the browser cache for this file)

Answer (score 0):

I notice some problems with the icons when the `mod_pagespeed` was installed. Maybe you have this also installed. Disabling is then required for the backend.

Comment: mod_pagespeed is not installed

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem and a frame (where the rte is in) reload does the trick.